# How do I display URL that is passed from the model in my View in ASPX?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an error message, which is may contain a URL, that gets passed to the view.

How do I display part of the message (Mode.errormessage) as a link and not as Html encoded text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should describe a bit more and give an example, but this should do the work...

`<a href="<%= Model.errormessage %>">Click here.</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Html.Raw()` method in view , for example: `<a href="@Html.Raw(errorMsg)" ></a>`

Answer (score 0):

have you looked into using Html.ActionLink ?